# Difference between two logical expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let M(x, y) be "x has sent y an e-mail message" and T(x, y) be " x has telephoned y, " where the domain consists of all students in your class. Use quantifiers to express each of these statements.

g. There is a student in your class who sent every one else in your class an email message.

I answer  ∃x( x ≠ y ∧ ∀ M (x, y) )

But answer on text book is  ∃x( x ≠ y → ∀ M (x, y) )

i. There are two different students in your class who have sent each other e-mail messages.

I answer ∃x∃y( x ≠ y→ ∀ (M (x, y) ∧ M( y, x)))

But answer on text book is ∃x∃y( x ≠ y ∧ ∀ (M (x, y) ∧ M( y, x)))

I am confused about the use of → and ∧ on almost all the question.
Can someone explain two differences here, and perhaps explain it by translating to English?

Answer (score 1):

> g. There is a student in your class who sent every one else in your class an email message.
>
> - My answer: ∃x( x ≠ y ∧ ∀ M (x, y) )
> - Text book's answer: ∃x( x ≠ y → ∀ M (x, y) )

In my opinion, neither of those answers are correct. Namely, where does the first occurrence of the $y$ come from in each of those answers? These occurrences of $y$s are unbound. Having unbound variables is usually not what you want *unless* you have these variables in your context. But your text book does not define $y$ for this exercise, does it?

I would have answered this:

$$\exists x.\ \forall y.\ x \neq y \Rightarrow M(x, y)$$

This translates to

> There is a student, which we call $x$, such that for every student, which we will refer to as $y$, we have that if they are different students, then $x$ sent a message to $y$.

Let me explain why your answer is incorrect. You said the following:

```
∃x( x ≠ y ∧ ∀ M (x, y) ).
        ^            ^
```

Those two occurrences of the name $y$ refer to different variables! The left $y$ accesses an unbound $y$ of the outer scope, which as described above seems to have been magically introduced somehow. The right $y$ refers to the variable bound in the forall quantifier $\forall$ just before the "M". Now compare that to the meaning you intended to capture:

```
There is a student in your class who sent every one else in your class an email message.
                                      ^           ^
```

The "every one else" student is the *same* student who acts as the sender. You see that here both natural language "variables" (one being implicit in the "to send" verb) refer to the same entity, which was not the case in your formula. This is a pretty good indicator of something being wrong.

---

> i. There are two different students in your class who have sent each other e-> mail messages.
>
> - My answer: ∃x∃y( x ≠ y→ ∀ (M (x, y) ∧ M( y, x)))
> - Text book's answer: ∃x∃y( x ≠ y ∧ ∀ (M (x, y) ∧ M( y, x)))

Again, I deem both answers to be wrong. We don't need the forall quantifier at all here.

I would answer:

$$\exists x.\ \exists y.\ x \neq y \wedge M(x, y) \wedge M(y, x)$$

Perhaps you could clarify why you thought you needed a forall quantifier here? I have a hard time coming up with a counter-explanation without understanding your reasoning itself.

---

In all honesty, I'd look for a different text book. The fact that solutions to such simple questions are wrong is alarming! (Of course not "simple" for the beginner, but for the expert, which the authors hopefully are if they wrote a book on that topic.)